# onbeforeunload not working at all

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
(function() {
      window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          alert("hi")
          console.log("unloading");
      };
})();
```

I also have this code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
   alert("hi")
   console.log("unloading")
});
```

None of them seem to work. All I want to do is log when the user tries to leave the page, but this isn't happening (latest Chrome, latest Firefox, Edge....), can anybody shed some light on why it's not working?

Comment: This works nicely, anyway `alert()` is not showing up. I guess it's blocked in that state https://jsfiddle.net/tbnnpz56/2/ (Hit run multiple times and watch the console)

Answer (score 3):

> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more
>   details.
>   Note also that various mobile browsers ignore the result of the event
>   (that is, they do not ask the user for confirmation). Firefox has a
>   hidden preference in about:config to do the same. In essence this
>   means the user always confirms that the document may be unloaded.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Notes)

Also, use `return` statement to prompt user before leaving

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
   return "hi";
});
```

Comment: I do NOT want to prompt the user, I just want to intercept the event and do stuff based on it

Comment: What stuff do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to check if the page actually asked the user if he wants to leave the page.

Comment: I've noticed that testing this in Firefox is intermittent, as if it remembers my answer to leave page. When I tested in IE it consistently shows the console.log, dialog box of the returned string, and even the alert box.

Comment: You can "do stuff", but as you can see "alert" likely won't work

Comment: Other questions on SO also indicate that Ajax calls are not possible depending on browser but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          console.log("unloading");
          return "Hi";
      };
```

That will alert `Hi` when page unloads and also prints `unloading` in console

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    return "Write something clever here...";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
  
  </body>
```

Comment: I do NOT want to prompt the user, I just want to intercept the event and do stuff based on it

Comment: @mariostoilov Do you have found a solution to show call the function without prompt the user?

Comment: I cannot recall If i did. I am long gone from the project that required this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return from the onbeforeunload:

```
(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
      alert("hi")
      console.log("unloading");
      return null;
      };
    })();
```